# Tratando de armar una ruta con variables php

Tags: php

En una página muestro los datos de un usuario entre ellos tengo almacenado la fotografía que se almacena con el numero de id de usuario en una carpeta que es el id de usuario. Osea, la ruta sería

```
/images/usuarios/{idusuario}/{idusuario.jpg/png}
```

y para mostrar la fotografía cargo lo siguiente:

```
<img class="ui centered small circular image" src="../../images/usuarios/<?php $idusuario; ?>/<?php $idusuario; ?>.jpg">
```

bueno, resulta que no funciona... 
como podría construir esa ruta de una forma correcta ?

por ejemplo si el id de usuario fuera "16" la ruta de la imagen sería:

```
/images/usuarios/16/16.jpg
```

Comment: intenta con:  <img class="ui centered small circular image" src="../../images/usuarios/<?php echo $idusuario; ?>/<?php echo $idusuario; ?>.jpg">

Comment: tenes razon !!! me olvidé el maldito "echo" !!! gracias Alejandro !!!

Comment: @AlejandroMedina ponlo como respuesta y MNibor marcala como correcta si soluciono tu problema otros usuarios pueden necesitar la misma ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
<img class="ui centered small circular image" src="../../images/usuarios/<?php echo $idusuario; ?>/<?php echo $idusuario; ?>.jpg">
```